# Even or Odd Numbers - Function not subscriptable

Tags: python-3.x

I want to write a function that determines whether there's an odd or even number of elements in an array.

python

```
def middle_element(list):
  if len(list)%2 == 0:
    return 'Even'
  else:
    return 'Odd'
```

However, I get --> 'function object is not subscriptable.' Thanks for reading, helping me out!

Comment: Do you have something else named `middle_element` ?

Comment: You probably have two objects both named `middle_element`.

Comment: How do you call the function?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that example out. Actually, I have seen that one before I wrote mine, but I thought they are different as in the other example the list was defined outside of the function and not inside the function like it was in my example.

Comment: Thanks MisterMiyagi! I actually called the function with square brackets instead of parantheses, which was the solution!